# Bibliography style apalike: how to include the author's abbreviated first name in the citation call-out?

Tags: natbib, apa-style

I'm using the `natbib` package and the `apalike` bibliography style. If I write:

```
\citet{reimann2017}
```

I get the following citation call-out:

> Reimann (2017)

And in the formatted bibliography it shows:

> Reimann, G. (2017). Blablablabla.

i.e., it shows the abbreviated first name of the author (here: "G.") after the author's surname.

Now my professor asks that the abbreviated first name show up in the citation call-out as well, as follows:

> Reimann G. (2017)

Any suggestions for how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you proceed as follows:

- Find the file `apalike.bst` in your TeX distribution. Make a copy of this file and call the copy, say, `apalike-mod.bst`. (Don't edit an un-renamed original file of the TeX distribution directly.)
- Open the file `apalike-mod.bst` in a text editor. The program you use to edit your tex files will do fine.
- In the file `apalike-mod.bst`, find the function `format.lab.names`. (In my copy of the file, this function starts on line 841.)
- Inside this function, change both instances of `"{vv~}{ll}"` to `"{vv~}{ll}{~f.}"`.

  I trust that you can guess -- correctly! -- that `f.` represents the truncated first name followed by `.`.
- Save the file `apalike-mod.bst` either in the directory where your main tex file is located or in a directory that's searched automatically by BibTeX. If you choose the latter option, be sure to also update the filename database of your TeX distribution suitably.
- In your main tex file, change the instruction `\bibliographystyle{apalike}` to `\bibliographystyle{apalike-mod}` and perform a full recompile cycle -- LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more -- to propagate all changes.

Speaking for myself, I can't help but remark that adding abbreviated first names to the citation call-outs serves no useful purpose unless you are citing works of `G. Reimann`, `B. Reimann`, `T. Reimann`, and maybe a few other Reimanns more all in one and the same document.

---

A full MWE (minimum working example) and its output (highlighting added manually):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@misc{r:2017,author="Gustav Reimann", title="Blablablabla", year=2017}
@misc{a,author="Anne Author", title="x", year=3001}
@misc{ab,author="Anne Author and Brenda Buthor", title="xy", year=3002}
@misc{abc,author="Anne Author and Brenda Buthor and Carla Cuthor", title="xyz", year=3003}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike-mod}
\begin{document}
\citet{r:2017}

\cite{a}, \citep{ab}, \citet{abc}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```